# How to calculate monthly CPI on a private loan over a couple of years?

Tags: interest, inflation, cpi

I have borrowed money from a family member, and I have been keeping track of exactly how much I owe them down to fractions of cents. The amount owed has been steadily growing by a couple of hundred dollars each month.

The problem is inflation is starting to make a significant difference on the value of money, and I haven't been adjusting for inflation OR interest.

I think I should apply interest after indexation.

I've got a better idea of how to calculate interest compared to indexation, however, I'm still having trouble with interest.

I use the annual fixed interest rate of 5% and multiply it by the accumulative debt, divided by 12 months. Adding that amount to a new accumulative debt column should yield the total owed, but since I haven't been adding interest to the original accumulative debt amounts, I believe there's a slight difference in the amount.

I'm not sure how to calculate this difference, but I believe once it's calculated for each month that I'll have to use a different method of calculating interest for future months where interest is accounted for, and I don't know how to do that, either. Perhaps a new 'helper' column? I don't know.

With indexation, I believe I also have to calculate with the accumulative debt. The problem I'm facing is that sometimes the indexed amount is negative when I believe it should be positive.

I got the quarterly CPI figures from the abs website, for example [from here](https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/economy/price-indexes-and-inflation/consumer-price-index-australia/latest-release), going back for each quarter since the loan inception, and copied for each of the 3 months in the quarter.

I see that the CPI formula is calculated by ((new level/old level)-1)*100% .

So with the CPI formula, I have been using the most recent CPI level ('new') and then the CPI level of when the monthly accrued amount is loaned ('old') and then multiplying that amount by the accumulative loan amount. Then, I add that to the original accumulative amount in a new column.

Similarly with interest, I'm not sure how to calculate the slight differences. I figure that the indexation amount should vary slightly up or down (more up recently) but it seems to be the opposite.

For instance, in August of 2022, the 'old' CPI level is 3.2. The 'current' CPI level is always 0.9 for each month (latest available level at time of writing) for the September quarter (so the final amount is really only accurate for the amounts recorded up until Sept-December) so I've been using the formula ((0.9/3.2)-1)*100% = -0.72% which yields a negative amount in the calculated monthly indexation, when I believe it should be positive. In fact, the last few rows are negative when I think they should be positive.

Am I applying the indexation formula incorrectly in my spreadsheet?

How do I calculate indexation and interest every month up until the most recent quarter?

After the debt amount is indexed and interest applied correctly every month, how do I calculate the newly applied debt amount figures from then on?

Any guidance is appreciated.

edit: As requested, here's a screenshot:
[first 4 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zy5sW.png)

The formulas are as follows:

G9=(($I$3/$F9)-1)*100%
G10=(($I$3/$F10)-1)*100%

H9=0
H10=260.45
(raw values)

I9=0.00
I10=H10-H9

J9=($G9*$H9)/100
J10=($G10*$H10)/100

K9=I9+J9
K10=I10+J10

L9=0
L10=H10+J10

M9=L9*$I$4/100/12
M10=L10*$I$4/100/12

N9=K9+M9
N10=K10+M10

O9=0
O10=O9+N10

Comment: "new level" and "old level" are the old and new *prices*, not cpi values. E.g. if the basket prices were 100$ last year and are 110$ today, the cpi is 10% [ (110/100-1)*100% ]. The cpi is basically the interest rate you would have to pay (or get) to not lose money value to inflation, so just pay this as interest, plus the interest you want to pay anyway (e.g. a variable interest rate). Your approach feels a bit complicated (probably as a result of the misinterpretation), maybe show some lines of your table to make it easier to understand what you are calculating and what you want to calculate.

Comment: updated edit with a screenshot and formulas, hope that explains it better - i'm still a bit confused with the cpi, i don't already know how much it was worth in the given year/month - that's what i'm trying to calculate

Comment: i think what i wanted to calculate was the **inflation rate** not the cpi, but this is apparently calculated using the old and new cpi levels using the formula `subtracting the past cost of an item or service from its current price, and dividing that result by the past cost`

Comment: Sorry, your calculation is still not clear to me, and I still think you are misunderstanding the cpi levels (which in turn cause my confusion). Again: the cpi values ARE the inflation values. I don't really know where you get old/new cpi levels, but a cpi value of e.g. 2 against the previous year (or quarter) means: if you had to pay 100$ last year, you have to pay 102$ this year. THESE are the old/new levels that are meant (e.g. (102$/100$-1)*100=2% inflation). So if you know the cpi value (e.g. against last year), you can just pay cpi % interest on the debt for last year.

Comment: i'm still confused.

the cpi figures are from the australian bureau of statistics, and are released every quarter. i could apply yearly averages or quarterly averages and i chose quarterly. i think these averages are calculated in comparison to the previous year or quarter.

i think i need to use the most current cpi level `0.9` and also use the cpi level for the month in question (eg. `0.4` for february or `0.8` for march) and use these figures to calculate a rate for each month.

i can't just apply it like interest for each given month because it has to somehow reflect today's value.

Comment: ok, so perhaps i wasn't explaining myself properly. the figures are from each quarter, such as [here for the march quarter of 2021](https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/economy/price-indexes-and-inflation/consumer-price-index-australia/mar-2021) and [here for the june quarter of 2021](https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/economy/price-indexes-and-inflation/consumer-price-index-australia/jun-2021) from the abs - i just don't know how to use these figures, or if i should be using these figures at all?

Comment: Ok, then I also try again: quarterly cpi number from your 1st link: 0.6, and from your 2nd link: 0.8. What those numbers mean is: if you had a debt of $10.000 in Dec 2020, in Mar 2021, it should be $10.000*(1+0.6%)=$10.060 to make up for inflation (e.g. so that you can buy as much food/gas/... with $10.060 as with $10.000 3 month ago). And if you had a debt of $10.060 in Mar 2021, it would be $10.060*(1+0.8%)=$10.140,48 in Jun 2021. That's all you need to do: use these numbers like a quartly interest rate (plus your 5%/year = 1.23%/3month). There is no (new/old-1)-calculation anywhere.

Comment: thank you very much for explaining, i think i understand how now for those particular sequential months, but what about if i wanted to calculate the same amount from december 2020 to march 2021, and then to, say, [february of 2022](https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/economy/price-indexes-and-inflation/consumer-price-index-australia/mar-2022)? do i need to keep track of each quarterly cpi up until february 2022?

Comment: i think i've finally got it. [here's the formulas](https://i.imgur.com/C4fQNVs.png) and [here's the results](https://i.imgur.com/lqeAzgI.png). does this look right? i'm worried the running cumulative total in the right-most column isn't correct

Comment: ok, just a correction, i've double-and-triple-checked the formulas this time, and i think i've got it - [here's the formulas](https://i.imgur.com/4uftmqA.png) and [here's the results](https://i.imgur.com/tzuruNU.png) - this time i've added the previous quarter's indexation and interest to each new quarter - if this looks completely correct, let me know, and i'll answer my own question mentioning all the problems i went through so others won't make the same mistakes